# Gizmo Lines not Drawing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a suspension script to use in a racing game, and want to draw some lines with Gizmos to help correctly set the spring length and travel. However, only one of the lines are appearing.

Here's the code I have currently:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Suspension : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;

    [Header("Suspension")]
    [SerializeField] float restLength;
    [SerializeField] float springTravel;
    [SerializeField] float springStiffness;
    [SerializeField] float damperStiffness;

    private float minLength;
    private float maxLength;
    private float previousLength;
    private float springLength;
    private float springVelocity;
    private float springForce;
    private float damperForce;

    private Vector3 suspensionForce;

    [Header("Wheel")]
    [SerializeField] float wheelRadius;

    [Header ("Ground Information")]
    public bool touchingGround;
    public Vector3 groundNormal;
    void Awake()
    {
        rb = transform.root.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        minLength = restLength - springTravel;
        maxLength = restLength + springTravel;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + (restLength * -this.transform.up), Color.red, 0.0f, false);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (0.1f * this.transform.forward), transform.position + (0.1f * this.transform.forward) + (minLength * -this.transform.up), Color.yellow, 0.0f, false);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (0.1f * -this.transform.forward), transform.position + (0.1f * -this.transform.forward) + (maxLength * -this.transform.up), Color.white, 0.0f, false);
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out RaycastHit hit, maxLength + wheelRadius))
        {
            touchingGround = true;
            groundNormal = hit.normal;

            previousLength = springLength;
            springLength = hit.distance - wheelRadius;
            springLength = Mathf.Clamp(springLength, minLength, maxLength);
            springVelocity = (previousLength - springLength) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            springForce = springStiffness * (restLength - springLength);
            damperForce = damperStiffness * springVelocity;

            suspensionForce = (springForce + damperForce) * transform.up;
            rb.AddForceAtPosition(suspensionForce, hit.point);
        }
        else
        {
            touchingGround = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos() 
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + (restLength * -this.transform.up));
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + (0.1f * this.transform.forward), transform.position + (0.1f * this.transform.forward) + (minLength * -this.transform.up));
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position + (0.1f * -this.transform.forward), transform.position + (0.1f * -this.transform.forward) + (maxLength * -this.transform.up));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I also tried to do this with Debug.DrawLine, which worked as expected, but I'd like to be able to see the lines before hitting play and have them automatically adjust as I change the input variables.

What I'm expecting to happen is for a red line of restLength to appear going down from the suspension object's position, and to either side of it, yellow and white lines that start from the same height, but have lengths of minLength and maxLength, respectively.

This is what it looks like when the script compiles, though:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV5Fo.png)
The red line appears where I want, but none of the others do. I've also tried commenting out the line after Gizmos.color is set to red, and all that causes is no lines to appear.

Comment: where are you looking for your gizmos and have you turned them on in the scene view where you will find them

Answer (score 0):

what about if u remove the duration parameter?
that should be work.

```
    void FixedUpdate()
{
    //......

    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + (restLength * -this.transform.up), Color.red);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (0.1f * this.transform.forward), transform.position + (0.1f * this.transform.forward) + (minLength * -this.transform.up), Color.yellow);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (0.1f * -this.transform.forward), transform.position + (0.1f * -this.transform.forward) + (maxLength * -this.transform.up), Color.white);

    //....
}
```

Comment: Those lines are working as expected. I'm worried about the code lower down in the 'OnDrawGizmos()' block, which I need to work in order to see the lines in Edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `minLength` and `maxLength` aren't set until you press play.
You can add the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` tag to your class and it will run awake in the editor and calculate those values.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Suspension : MonoBehaviour
```

`OnDrawGizmos` will run in both edit and play modes, however without the `ExecuteInEditMode` the internal values will not be calculated using functions like `Awake`, `Start`, `Update`, etc.

`Awake` will only run once in the editor, and after pressing play those values will be reset.  You can use `OnEnable` to set those values and they should be set each time in the editor.  Serializing those values will prevent them being reset if you want to use `Awake`.

Comment: This got me on the right track, but minLength and maxLength still aren't updating every frame in Edit mode as I'd like, and I'd rather not have to update them to the same values every frame in Play Mode. Is there a way to make code execute every frame in Edit mode, but only once in Play mode? Also, I should've mentioned before that I am tweaking the travel values from the Prefab menu.

Comment: If you serialize the value it will "stick".  Just add `[SerializeField] [HideInInspector]` to those fields, and get the `Awake` to fire once in the editor, it'll save.

Comment: Think I'm almost there, but what do you mean by getting Awake to fire in the editor?

Comment: By re-adding the component to the object, Awake will run/fire in the editor.